# Git remote has been created, and what should I do in the next

Tags: git

Someone use my code to create a remote git repository, and what should I do to make a connection with the remote so that I can begin committing and pushing code to remote? 
Should I use git clone? I think that will overlay my local project(but it's ok for me, since the code in the remote and in the local are the same).
I just want to know the best practice to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your `git` repo on your local machine, you can do

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

in a command line, where `url` is, quite naturally, the URL of the remote.

What this command does is tell the `git` repo that it should now look to this remote repo, named `origin`, for commits and updates, and push to it when you do a `git push`.

If your code isn't in a `git` repo on your local machine (i.e. is unversioned), what you should do is this:

```
git clone <url>
```

into a separate folder outside of your source tree. This will copy the contents of the remote into that folder, as well as the `git` history, and implicitly apply the command above to it. Then you can delete the unversioned folder, if there are no differences between the two.

Comment: For the first solution, do I need to go the folder which contain all the files of my project and then git init to create a git repo for this project before I do the "git remote add origin <url>"? And by the way the project is created by "git clone" at the beginning from certain boilerplates of someone's github.

Comment: The first solution assumes that the remote was created from an existing `git` repo in some way, and that the code on your local machine is already versioned with `git`. If it is not, you should use the second solution.